# AWS Cloudsearch: cs-configure-from-batches Resource not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I am attempting to add index fields to a cloudSearch domain I have just created, but I am getting errors doing so. 
I create the domain using:

```
aws cloudsearch create-domain --domain-name test-run
```

If I view information about the domain using the below command I get results including indication the the domain has been created.

```
aws cloudsearch describe-domains --domain-name test-run
```

I can also view this information using  the CloudSearch console.

However, when I try to run

```
cs-configure-from-batches --domain-name test-run --source scripts/SeedFile.json -c ~/.aws/credentials
```

I get the below error

```
Domain not found: test-run (Service: AmazonCloudSearchv2; Status Code: 409; Error Code: ResourceNotFound;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

the endpoint defaults to a us east endpoint. I needed to specify us-west with --endpoint on the command